# REST Calls in Python

Tags: python, json, firebase

I'm trying to write a script to port my existing database into Firebase. My data is stored in JSON and I thought I could just pull the JSON and then send that as data into a POST to my Firebase.

```
def Post_And_Recieve_JSON(url, data, headers):
    print("Compiling query...")
    Post_And_Recieve_JSON.url = url
    Post_And_Recieve_JSON.headers = headers
    Post_And_Recieve_JSON.data = (data)

    print("Sending request...")
    request = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=data,headers=headers)
    print("Recieving response...")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

    print("Reading response...")
    response_data = response.read()
    print("Converting into usable format...")
    response_data_JSON = json.loads(response_data.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))

    return response_data_JSON

for all_users in existing_database:
    full_data.append(Post_And_Recieve_JSON(...)

for item in full_data:
    url = 'firebaseurlhere ' + item['profileId'] + '.json'
    data = json.dumps(item).encode('ascii')
    Post_And_Recieve_JSON(url, data, headers)
```

Where full_data is a list of JSON objects I've properly pulled from teh existing database.

I'm getting "http.client.BadStatusLine: ''"

Comment: I'd like to use the firebase python helper, http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/, but that is for python2.7. I need urllib and urllib.request from python3 to pull my original data.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using the firebase python lib found here: http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/

I used pip3 to install it. I just wish I could have done it the same way I do other REST calls instead of requiring a new lib.

```
full_data = []
from firebase import *
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://secret_url.firebaseio.com/', None)

for id in id_list:
    print(str(id))
    url = 'from_url'
    try:
        result = firebase.put('/users/ ' + str(id) + '/',    data=Post_And_Recieve_JSON(url, None, headers)["payload"], name='Data')
    except:
        print('Skipping a user')
```